# Filter an array list result from query builder in model in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, query-builder

I have a query function in my model to get list user and it return an array data to my repository class:

Model.php:

```
public function getUser()
{
    return $this->select("{$this->table}.'*'")
                ->get();
}
```

Here is an example for the data:

```
[
    [
        "user_id":1,
        "fullname":"amdv",
        "is_active":0
    ],
    [
        "user_id":2,
        "fullname":"abc",
        "is_active":1
    ],
    [
        "user_id":3,
        "fullname":"zyz",
        "is_active":1
    ]
]
```

Now I want to check if is_active = 1, it continue check that user with other condition in other query

In my model, I have another query function with param is user id

Model.php:

```
public function checkUserAvailable($userId)
{
    return $this->select("{$this->table}.'*'")
                ->join('other_table', 'join-condition')
                ->where('user_id', $userId)
                ->get();
}
```

But this function return data too, I don't know how to check this.
Thank you very much!

Comment: Don't quite get what you want. What is the another query function in model - can you post the code for that function. Do you want to pass user_id from this array to the other function?

Comment: You want to "remove user" form database? "which is not available".. Modify your "query function in my model to get list user" to get only user ids' then give the list to the second function.

Comment: do you actually have an array or do you have a collection of models?

Answer (score 0):

```
$data = [
    [
        "user_id":1,
        "fullname":"amdv",
        "is_active":1
    ],
    [
        "user_id":2,
        "fullname":"abc",
        "is_active":1
    ],
    [
        "user_id":3,
        "fullname":"zyz",
        "is_active":1
    ]
];

$filtered = collect($data)->filter(function($user) {
    return User::someMethodYouMentioned($user['user_id']);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to filter out the ones that are not active you can use `array_filter` with a callback:

```
$filtered = array_filter($array, fn ($i) => $i['is_active']);
```

If you want to use those values to call a function and then get those results you can use `array_map`:

```
$res = array_map([$this, 'checkUserAvailable'], array_column($filtered, 'user_id'));
```

You can also do this with the Collection methods if you would like:

```
collect($array)->where('is_active', 1)
    ->pluck('user_id')
    ->map([$this, 'checkUserAvailable'])
```

Though, I am not sure what else you need to be checking besides that `is_active` is true.

Answer (score 0):

From what I understand is that you want to check the data from the array returned by the first function and if `is_active = 1` then you want to check if the user is available via the second function in your model

```php
//Get the user_id of records where is_active === 1
$available = collect($data)
    ->reject(fn($user) => $user['is_active'] !== 1)
    ->pluck('user_id')
    ->map(fn($id) => User::checkUserAvailable($id));
```

For this to work the checkUserAvailable needs to be a static function.

However looking at both the functions - question arises why do you need to run multiple database queries to check for user available via the second function.

You can modify the query in the second function to check for `is_active`

```php
public static function checkUserAvailable()
{
    return static::query()
        ->join('other_table', 'join-condition')
        ->where('is_active', 1)
        ->get();
}
```

Or if you still want to first get a list of all users as array and then check for availability, you could define the checkUserAvailable as a scope on the model

```php
public function scopeCheckUserAvailable($query, $id)
{
    $ids = Arr::wrap($id);

    return $query->join('other_table', 'join-condition')
        ->whereIn('user_id', $ids);
}
```

Then you can get the data from the `getUser()` function and perform the second check like

```php
//Get the user_id of records where is_active === 1
$checkIds = collect($data)
    ->reject(fn($user) => $user['is_active'] !== 1)
    ->pluck('user_id')
    ->all();

$availableUsers = User::checkAvailableUsers($checkIds)->get();
```